# Updating value via trigger AFTER UPDATE Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I'm developing a small library database and I don't want to allow someone to update someone's ID. But I need to use AFTER UPDATE and FOR EACH STATEMENT (which I'm told is Oracle's default). So, basically, if someone updates the customer info and alter his/her ID or mistypes it, the trigger will automatically update it again to the old value. The problem is that Oracle won't let me use :NEW and :OLD when using FOR EACH STATEMENT. Are there any workarounds to this issue?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER alter_id_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON CUSTOMER
BEGIN
   UPDATE CUSTOMER SET ID = :OLD.ID
   WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
END;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are `cliente` and `customer` two different tables?  Or are they the same table?  A statement-level trigger does not have access to the `:new` or `:old` pseudo-records, you'd need a row-level trigger for that.

Comment: They are the same, I forgot to translate it. Isn't there any other way to set the old ID into the new one without having a row-level trigger? :(

Comment: If you want to make row-level changes to the data, why would you not want a row-level trigger?  If you don't want to allow someone to change the `customer.id`, why would you even make that an editable field in the application or generate the `UPDATE` statement from the application in the first place?  It seems odd to want to allow the application to modify the `id` but then create a trigger that changes the data back.  Plus, it seems likely that a table like `customer` would have child tables whose foreign keys would automatically prevent the `id` from being changed.

Comment: The topic is pretty thoroughly discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8330884/1680777

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code for trigger. 
**Changes done:**

1. Using BEFORE UPDATE instead of AFTER UPDATE.
2. Setting the value of ID to what it was previously. (The ID Field would never be modified)

   `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ALTER_ID_TRIGGER
   BEFORE UPDATE ON CUSTOMER
   BEGIN
      SET :NEW.ID = :OLD.ID
   END;`

**Note:** With **[BEFORE UPDATE:](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php)**

- You can not create a BEFORE trigger on a view.
- You **can update** the :NEW values.
- You **can not update** the :OLD values.

Comment: its work after add `FOR EACH ROW` because `REFERENCING` allowed in row level

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a *before* update trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER alter_id_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON CUSTOMER
BEGIN
   SET :NEW.ID = :OLD.ID
END;
```

You could test to see if the value is being changed, but that seems unnecessary.