# ORACLE :missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

---

ORACLE :missing right parenthesis

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS  MODIFY 
(RECEIVED_DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

oracle 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `ON UPDATE` clause in Oracle column definitions. Oracle is complaining because it expects a closing parenthesis after `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to keep the date of the last time you update. For that you need an update trigger in your table.

Check this answer.

[Updating value via trigger AFTER UPDATE Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254466/updating-value-via-trigger-after-update-oracle-11g)